# Printing a PDF in Landscape on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, airprint

I am working on an app that can print a created PDF.  The PDF is 11 x 8.5, so I need it to print landscape mode, but I am having issues with getting that orientation set properly.  Here is what I have for the print.

```
- (void)printit {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:selectedCountry];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if  (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:pdfData] ) {
        pic.delegate = self;
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = selectedCountry;
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexNone;
        pic.printInfo = printInfo;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;
        pic.printingItem = pdfData;
               void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
        ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
                       if (!completed && error)
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u",
                      error.domain, error.code);
        };
        //if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        //    [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES
        //                completionHandler:completionHandler];
      //  }
   // else {
            [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
       // }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;
```

Make sure its added before you assign the UIPrintInfo to the UIPrintInteractionController --

```
pic.printInfo = printInfo;
```

Hopefully this resolves the issue for you.